# Angularjs Jasmine unit testing a controller : $scope and ionicPopupProvider is undefined

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, scope, controller, jasmine

I'm trying to test my simple controller but seems like nothing is working.
the controller:

```
  userCtrlMod.controller('resetCtrl',
  ['$scope', '$ionicPopup', '$timeout','resetPwd',
  function($scope, $ionicPopup, $timeout, resetPwd){

  $scope.reset = function(){
    $scope.resetPopUp = $ionicPopup.show({
     templateUrl:'././templates/popup/reset.html',
     scope: $scope
    });
  }}]);
```

my test file :

```
describe("resetCtrl", function () {
var $myScope, $myController,  timeout;

beforeEach(module('dbooks.userCtrl'));

beforeEach(inject(function(
_$controller_,
_$rootScope_,
_$timeout_,
$ionicPopup
){
  $myController = _$controller_;
  $myScope = _$rootScope_;

  $myController = $controller('resetCtrl' , {
    $scope: $myScope,
    $resetPopUp : $ionicPopup
  });
}));

it("should have a $scope variable", function() {
    //console.log($myScope);
    expect($myScope).toBeDefined();
});});
```

I googled it but i could'nt find any solution, please someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.
the errors :

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $ionicPopupProvider <- $ionicPopup
>
> Uncaught Expected undefined to be defined.
>       at Object.

Comment: can you provide the complete code?

Comment: that's all what is related to the test I'm trying to do

Comment: can i provide you with an example, like a simple add two numbers one

Comment: thank you i already found a lot of examples in google like the one you mentioned, but my problem is that i think i'm missing something because my scope is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide all required dependencies when creating controller in test. You have to provide all dependencies required by the controller:

```
describe("resetCtrl", function () {
    var $myScope, $myController,  timeout;

    beforeEach(module('dbooks.userCtrl'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(
        _$controller_,
        _$rootScope_,
        _$timeout_,
        $ionicPopup
    ){
        $myController = _$controller_;
        $myScope = _$rootScope_;
        var resetPwd = {
            someResetmethod: jasmine.createSpy('rese')
        };

        $myController = $controller('resetCtrl' , {
            $scope: $myScope,
            $ionicPopup: $ionicPopup,
            $timeout: _$timeout_,
            resetPwd: resetPwd 
        });
    }));

    it("should have a $scope variable", function() {
        //console.log($myScope);
        expect($myScope).toBeDefined();
    });

}
```

Please note that you can inject mocked objects as dependencies - in above code instead of original `resetPwd` mocked object with spy as method is injected. The important thing is that you have to provide all dependencies used by your controller and if you inject mocked objects those object of course have to include required methods and properties.

Comment: thank you for answering, but tried what you toldme but still i got the same problem, the problem is even scope in not defined what do you think i miss in my code? its like nothing is injected

Comment: hmm...In test you initialize module named `dbooks.userCtrl` - is this the name of module stored in `userCtrlMod` variable?

Comment: @AbirBk There could be also another problem: you have to make sure that  module with `$ionicPopup` service is available in tests. So you have to also initialize module on which this service is defined otherwise this service can't be injected in your tests because angular is not aware of this. So you have to add something like this: `beforeEach(module('nameOfModuleWithIonicPopupService'));`

Comment: this is how it is my module :
   userCtrlMod = angular.module('dbooks.userCtrl', ['dbooks.directives']);
even if i used userCtrlMod i got the same error...

Comment: @AbirBk plesae see my previous comment. During tests you have to also initialize module that includes `$ionicPopup` service.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
$myScope =__$rootScope_.$new();
```

Comment: Any explanation?